# How do you stretch a background image's width?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to use a background image for a `footer` in CSS, however, `background-size:cover;` causes most the image to not be seen.Is there a way to only stretch it's width?
Here's my current .CSS

```
    footer
{
top:85%;
width:80%;
height:10%;
left:10%;
position:absolute;
z-index:99;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border:1;
background-image:url(images/Inside%20the%20rig.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: use `backrgound-size` to get the size you want..

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this, replace the 999px for the real height:

`background-size: 100% 999px;`

`background-repeat:no-repeat;`